# Failed to join three entity models in Query annotation via Spring JPA Data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have three tables and mapping JPA entity models as followings in jsf 2.x application.

```
Foo   Foo.java
Bar   Bar.java
Zoo   Zoo.java
```

The Foo has @oneToMany relationship to both Bar and Zoo in entity model context. In native sql, I was able to join three of them which worked fine.

```
select f.*, b.*, z.*
from Foo f
  inner join Bar b
    on f.foo_id = b.foo_id
      inner join Zoo z
        on z.foo_id = b.foo_id
          where b.name = 'barName' and z.type = 'zooType";
```

I was trying to translate native sql in Query annotation via Spring JPA Data however I was keep getting org.hibernate.hgql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token.

Can someone kindly enough to point out what I am doing wrong? I tried having "one inner join" but I got same exception.

```
@Query("select f from Foo f inner join f.bars b inner join f.zoos z " +
        "where b.name = ?1 " + 
        "where z.type = ?2")
List<Foo> findFoo(String name, String type);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, you write two where in the @Query block, maybe you should use

```
 @Query("select f from Foo f inner join f.bars b inner join f.zoos z " +
 "where b.name = ?1 " + 
 "and z.type = ?2")
List<Foo> findFoo(String name, String type);
```

instead :)